# Overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out why my overflow: hidden isn't working correctly. To my understanding, it will cut off anything out of the set dimensions, but with what I am working on it should show fully upon hovering. So I have text set within a div that is to be cut off until you hover over it. Once you hover over it the box needs to expand and show the hidden text. Below is the code and an image of what it needs to look like.

[image]

```css
.flexbox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 420px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
}

.flexbox>div {
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 295px;
  margin: -5px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px dimgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:hover {
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(1):hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(4):hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Rosario"
}

img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div><img src="http://prism.troy.edu/gpratt68237/images/GPP.png" alt="Good programming practice icon">
    <p>Good Programming Practices call attention to techniques that will help you produce programs that are clearer, more understandable and more maintainable.</p>
  </div>
  <div><img src="http://prism.troy.edu/gpratt68237/images/EPT.png" alt="Error prevention tip icon">
    <p>Error-Prevention Tips contain suggestions for exposing bugs and removing them from your programs; many describe aspects of programming that prevent bugs from getting into programs in the first place.</p>
  </div>
  <div><img src="http://prism.troy.edu/gpratt68237/images/CPE.png" alt="Common programming error icon">
    <p>Common Programming Errors point out the errors that students tend to make frequently. These Common Programming Errors reduce the likelihood that you'll make the same mistakes.</p>
  </div>
  <div><img src="http://prism.troy.edu/gpratt68237/images/SEO.png">
    <p>Software Engineering Observations highlight architectural and design issues that affect the construction of software systems, especially large-scale systems.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give `height: auto` for the `<p>` tag when hovering over the div.

Since SO doesn't load the images in that snippet, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zyn9mrs/) for you

```css
.flexbox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 420px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
}

.flexbox>div {
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 295px;
  margin: -5px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px dimgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flexbox>div:hover {
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Added this rule */
.flexbox > div:hover p {
  height: auto;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(1):hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.flexbox>div:nth-child(4):hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Rosario"
}

img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div><img src="http://prism.troy.edu/gpratt68237/images/GPP.png" alt="Good programming practice icon">
    <p>Good Programming Practices call attention to techniques that will help you produce programs that are clearer, more understandable and more maintainable.</p>
  </div>
  <div><img src="http://prism.troy.edu/gpratt68237/images/EPT.png" alt="Error prevention tip icon">
    <p>Error-Prevention Tips contain suggestions for exposing bugs and removing them from your programs; many describe aspects of programming that prevent bugs from getting into programs in the first place.</p>
  </div>
  <div><img src="http://prism.troy.edu/gpratt68237/images/CPE.png" alt="Common programming error icon">
    <p>Common Programming Errors point out the errors that students tend to make frequently. These Common Programming Errors reduce the likelihood that you'll make the same mistakes.</p>
  </div>
  <div><img src="http://prism.troy.edu/gpratt68237/images/SEO.png">
    <p>Software Engineering Observations highlight architectural and design issues that affect the construction of software systems, especially large-scale systems.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
p:hover { overflow: visible; }
```

you need this in your css